# How to change the axis values to correctly display even when zoomed in?

Tags: delphi, teechart

I wanted to ask how to increase the values of the axis to display data correctly?
I tried searching the teechart options but with no luck.

[image]

Comment: In this case, you should either (1) use one more digit in the number format (0.0000) on the left axis, or (2) increase the distance between the labels on the left axis. Which one do you want to do?

Comment: i would prefer to use more digits in the number format. I wasnt able to find that option in teechart options. They are very confusing.

Comment: `MyChart.Axes.Left.AxisValuesFormat := '0.0000';` works for me.

Comment: Yeah it absolutely did work and i also found the same setting in UI. posting a photo for others who might encounter my problem. You can make your answer the main one ill accept it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that comment until now. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should either

1. use one more digit in the number format (`0.0000`) on the left axis, or
2. increase the distance between the labels on the left axis.

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610736/how-to-change-the-axis-values-to-correctly-display-even-when-zoomed-in#comment116002199_65610736) to the question, the OP confirmed that the number format should be changed.

To do this at runtime, you can do

```
MyChart.Axes.Left.AxisValuesFormat := '0.0000';
```

It is also possible to do this [at design-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65611048/282848).

Answer (score 1):

Posting a photo for others who might get confused where this setting can be tuned in teechart Options

[image]